# Postgres - RDS - statement_timeout - aborted statements counter

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Is it possible to get the number of statements that were aborted because they were running for more than "statement_timeout" milliseconds? 
The statement_timeout parameter is useful to not let the database overload but I would like to configure an alert on aborted statements so that I can investigate the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

In standard PostgreSQL there is no view or statistic available for aborted statements due to `statement_timeout` parameter.

However there is a log entry for each aborted statement similar to:

```
2020-06-17 18:42:54.357 CEST [31946] ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
2020-06-17 18:42:54.357 CEST [31946] STATEMENT:  select * from pg_class;
```

So it is possible to scan PostgreSQL log.